# Remote Notifications Not Working After Update Of App Is Put Out

Tags: ios

I got remote notifications to work. When I pushed out an update through itunes connect, it got published. After I updated, my remote notifications don't work (Firebase). When I plug in my phone in my mac, then build it works fine and notifications go through.

When I have the build on my phone it works. When I have that build that's updated via itunes store, the message does not show up when it says sent.

Comment: After you updated from to which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a environment problem.

When u download from store it use Production certificate. (Need to be uploaded in your push service/server, same as your dev/sandbox one). Send Notification to Prod environment will work.

When u ran throw Xcode it **always** count as dev/sandbox. (even when u ran as Prod, does not matter). Send notification to dev environment will work.

That been said, seems like you are registering your device as dev/sandbox. That why u receive while running from Xcode and not from Store.

Or u did not upload your Prod certificate to your push service/server.

Comment: do you think you can use team viewer please I really need to get this.

Comment: do you have team viewer?

Comment: just downloaded it, whats your id?

Comment: try again same info

Answer (score 0):

When you plug in your phone with you mac you are running application in debug mode. While uploading app to app store its working in distribution environment. So you have to upload production APNS certificates also on firebase under your ios app configuration.